# Probability that digits are at their proper places.

Tags: probability

Suppose that the $4$ digits $1,2,3,4$ are written down in random order. What is the probability that at least one digit will occupy its proper place?

**My input:**

Required Probability is $\implies$ 
 $P$(one is at its proper place) $+$ $P$(two are at their proper place) $+$ $P$(three are at their proper place)

$P$(one is at its proper place) $=$ _ _ _ _ ; I fixed $1$ at first place then other can permutate in $6$ ways.

$P$(two are at their proper place) $=$ Fixed two here and gives other to permutate in $2$ ways.

$P$(three are at their proper place) $= $ When three are fixed only one digit is left and that gives one way and also $4 $ are placed properly as well .

That gives me  total of $9$ ways. Thus Probability = $\dfrac{9}{24}$

Its wrong I know I checked my answer. So please correct me here. Moreover, I tried to think of $1-P($no one is at their proper place$)$ but I failed.

Comment: The cases where no digit is in its proper place is called a [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).  There are many questions on the site about them

Comment: @RossMillikan I usually scroll down and check similar questions when I am writing question but couldn't see one that matches my problem.

Comment: Many times we just need the proper term for something.  Once we have the term the information is easy to find.

Comment: @RossMillikan I ll keep that in mind. Don't close or hold this, please .

Comment: If you are adding 1, 2, or 3 in the proper space you must assume that the rest are distinctly *not* in their proper s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate that exactly one is in the proper place you must calculate all the others are *not* in their places.  *And* you need to take into account that the one in the proper place can be any of the four.

So $N(1$ in right place$)$ [note: we are *not* calculating the probability but just counting the number] $= (4$ ways we can choose which one is in there right place$)\times(2\cdot 1$ ways the remaining three can be in the *wrong* places.$)=4*(2!)= 4\cdot 2 = 8$.

Likewise to calculate the ways we can choose two in the right place we must calculate the the remain two are in the wrong places.  There is only one way to do that (of the remaining two places only one is wrong).  But we must also count the number of ways we can pick which two are in the right place.  There are $4$ chooses for the first one and $3$ for the second but it doesn't matter which ones we choose first.

So $N(2)=(\text{# of ways to choose 2 correct from 4})\times(\text{# of ways remaining 2 are wrong}= {4\choose 2}\times(1!) = \frac {4!}{2!2!} = 6$.

And $N(3)=(\text{# of ways to choose 3 correct from 4})\times(\text{# of ways remaining 1 is wrong}= {3\choose 1}\times 0 = 3*0 = 0$

And $N(4) = (\text{# of ways four all 4 to be correct) = 4$.

So $N(\text{at least one correect}) = N(1) + N(2) + N(3) + N(4) = 8 + 6 + 0 + 1 = 15$

So $P(\text{at least one correct})=\frac {N(\text{at least one})}{N(\text{total combos})}= \frac {15}{4!} = \frac {15}{24} = \frac 58$.

===

To do $P(\text{at least one in the right place}) = 1 - P(\text{all in the wrong place})$ has a bit of  a trick to it.

$N(\text{all in the wrong place})$ is *NOT* $3! = 6$ and the thinking there are $3$ wrong spots for # $1$ and then $2$ wrong spots for number #$2$ and... is faulty.  If we place #$1$ in $3$ or $4$ then there are $2$ spots for number #$2$ *but* if we place #$1$ in in $2$ then there are $3$ wrong spots for #$2$!

Instead we should think: There are $3$ places we can put #$1$.  Let's put it in a spot and call that number $k$.  Now we have to put #$k$ somewhere.  The remaining spots are $1$ and two others.  If we put #$k$ in $1$ then we must  switch the two remaining spots.  But if we put #$k$ in a spot other than $1$, let's say we put it in a spot we call $j$. Then we have two remaining numbers #$j$ and, lets call in #$m$, and we have two remaining spots, $1$ and $m$.  We must put #$m$ in $1$ and #$j$ in $1$.

So either way there are $3\cdot 3 = 9$  ways to put them all in the wrong spots.

So $P(\text{at least one in the right place}) = 1 - P(\text{all in the wrong place})= 1 - \frac {9}{24} = \frac {15}{24} = \frac 58$

Comment: I didn't get this part.  can you explain with example? "$(2  \cdot 1$ ways the remaining three can be in the wrong places$)$" .

Comment: You put #1 in the right place.  How many choices are there to put #2?  There are only 2 wrong places left.  If you put #2 in the 3s place how many places are there to put the 4?  Just 1.  If you put #2 in the 4s place how many places are there to put the 3.  Just 1.

Comment: Thanks and your one statement didn't render check it out.

Answer (score 1):

You calculated the wrong probability. The idea was correct, but the way the question is framed, you have to do something else.

What would happen with $3214$ for example? The digit $2$ is in its correct place but you did not account for this case. When you fix the number $2$ at the second spot, there are still $3$ other digits to permute around.

Comment: Ohh yes I should do it for $2 ,3 ,4$ as well right?

Comment: @Damn1o1 If you really just need one digit to be at its correct spot, then you will have $6$ permutations for each number you fix, just like you did for the digit $1$.

Comment: That's what I wrote in my input. I don't get it. Do I have to fix 2 ,3 then 4 to check all the ways? If I ll do that it will give me  6*4= 24

Comment: @Damn1o1 That's correct, but be careful: When fixing the digit $2$ for example, you have to keep in mind that the permutation 1234 has already been counted when fixing the digit $1$

Comment: Yes, I have just encountered that. So there is no way we can do this with the help of some proper mathematical formulation? Or do I have to write down all the possibilities like whole sample space?

Comment: I just figured them out. For $ 1 = (1,2,3,4) (1,2,4,3),(1,3,2,4),(1,3,4,2),(1,4,3,2) ,(1,4,2,3)$ for $2 =  (4,2,1,3),(4,2,3,1),(3,2,1,4).(3,2,4,1)$ for $3= (2,1,3,4),(4,1,3,2),(2,4,3,1)$ for $ 4 = (3,1,2,4),(2,3,1,4)$