# Find the probability that at least one digit will occupy its proper place.

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose that the three digits $1$,$2$ and $3$ are written down in random order. What is the probability that at least one digit will occupy its proper place?

Answer: $\frac{2}{3}$

My attempt:

In my first take I used the definition of probability with finite sample space and equally likely outcomes, which achieve:

$3\times 2 \times 1 = 6$ possibilities to arrange the three digits.

And the set with all these arrangements would be:

$S=\{(1,2,3);(1,3,2);(2,1,3);(2,3,1);(3,2,1);(3,1,2)\}$

And the asked probability is:

$P=\frac{4}{6}=\frac{2}{3}$

Trying to solve in a more general way which would be more efficient if the number of digits were much larger, I got this:

$P(\text{getting 1 digit at the right place})= \binom{3}{1}\times(\frac13)\times(\frac23)^2=\frac{4}{9}$

$P(\text{getting 2 digits at the right place})=\binom{3}{2}\times(\frac13)^2\times(\frac23)=\frac{2}{9}$

$P(\text{getting all digits at the right place})=\binom{3}{3}\times(\frac{1} {3})^3=\frac{1}{27}$

And the probability of getting at least one digit at the right place would be the sum of all three.

$P=\frac{4}{9} + \frac{2}{9} +\frac{1}{27}=\frac{19}{27}$

I know this problem could be solved like this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2882673. I just want to know why I didn't get the same result in the second attempt and if I could make some adjustment to achieve the wanted result.

Comment: The probability of getting all three digits in the right place is $\frac16$ from counting the outcomes. Also it isn't possible to get a fraction of $\frac19$ since there are only six outcomes. So we can see that your general methods must be wrong. Notice that there is only one way to get two digits in the right place, since the third digit has nowhere else to go if the first two are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because, for instance, when you count the outcomes with one digit in the right place, you are also counting outcomes where more than one digit is in the right place.  You already know that the sample space of permutations is $3! = 6$.  So it does not make sense that any of your probabilities would have a denominator of $9$ or $27$ because neither of these are a multiple of $6$.

Just looking back on the list of permutations, you can see that there is $1$ outcome in which all three digits are in the right place, thus you should have $1/6$ instead of $1/27$.  Moreover, there are **zero** outcomes in which exactly two of the three digits are in the right place, because there are only three digits:  if two of them are in the right place, the third must also be in the right place.

So you have to reconsider how you are doing your counting.  If you do, you will discover two concepts:  [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement), and the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).